# почему canvas при повороте куда то уползает?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, canvas

нажимаю rot  а изображение куда то уползает и поворачивается не на 90 градусов а больше

```js
var img;
var tttScale = 1;
var tttRotate = 1;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  img = new Image();
  var f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.URL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;

  img.onload = function() {

    ctx.scale((canvas.width / img.width), (canvas.width / img.width));
    //  ctx.rotate(20*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  };
};
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

function Move(a) {
  switch (a) {
    case 'plus':
      if (tttScale < 1) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
      tttScale = tttScale + 0.05;
      break;
    case 'mines':
      if (tttScale > 1) {
        tttScale = 1;
      }
    case 'rot':

      tttRotate = tttRotate + 90;
      break;
    default:
      tttScale = 1;
  }

  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  //ctx.scale(tttScale, tttScale);
  ctx.translate(canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.rotate(tttRotate * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  // alert(tttScale);

}

function doCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF8F00';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  //alert("111");
};
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body onload="doCanvas()">
  <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('mines')" target="_self" id="a_33ff_4">Minus</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('plus')">Plus</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="Move('rot')">rot</a>

  </br>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ;></canvas>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это из-за того, что вращение происходит вокруг центра вращения, который необходимо установить в центр вашего канваса. Вот примерно так:

```js
var img;
var tttScale = 1;
var tttRotate = 0;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
  var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  img = new Image();
  var f = document.getElementById("uploadimage").files[0],
    url = window.zURL || window.URL,
    src = url.createObjectURL(f);
  img.src = src;

  img.onload = function() {

    ctx.scale((canvas.width / img.width), (canvas.width / img.width));
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
  };
};
document.getElementById("uploadimage").addEventListener("change", draw, false)

window.Move = function(a) {
  tttRotate += 90/57.2958;;
  //ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  var x = img.width / 2;
  var y = img.width / 2;
  var width = img.width;
  var height = img.height;
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
  ctx.translate(x, y);
  ctx.rotate(tttRotate);
  ctx.drawImage(img, -width / 2, -height / 2, width, height);
  ctx.rotate(-tttRotate);
  ctx.translate(-x, -y);
}

function doCanvas() {
  ctx.fillStyle = '#FF8F00';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
};
```

```html
  <div>
   <input type="file" name="img" id="uploadimage">
   <a onClick="Move('rot')">rot</a>
  </div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" ;></canvas>
```